# Grails Taglib G:SELECT

Tags: html, grails, taglib

I am new to the Grails platform and became interested in the TagLib component.
I have this application wherein I am to create a time select [24-hour format selection] made of two `<select>` tag: hour and time. So far I have coded my theory in this manner.

```
def timePicker = { attrs ->
   out << "<g:select name='" + attrs['name'] + ".hour' from='${00..21}' />"
   out << "<g:select name='" + attrs['name'] + ".minute' from='${00..59}' />" 
}
```

However I can't display it in the page but it display the content of `out` in the webpage itself which is wrong. How can I have two `<select>` display properly on the `.gsp` by TagLib? Am i going to write it in the conventional `<select>` accompanied with `<option>` statements, or am going to utilize the `g.select(attrs)` syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use something like this:

```
def timePicker = { attrs ->
    def hours = 0..21
    def stringHours = hours.collect{ String.format('%02d', it) }

    def minutes = 0..59
    def stringMinutes = minutes.collect{ String.format('%02d', it) }

    out << "${select(from: stringHours, name: attrs.name + '.hour')}"
    out << "${select(from: stringMinutes, name: attrs.name + '.minute')}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method call in GSP only:

```
def timePicker = { attrs ->
    out << "${select(from: 00..21, name: attrs.name + '.hour')}"
    out << "${select(from: 00..59, name: attrs.name + '.minute')}"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to format single digit [0-9] to make it format into two digit `0\d`? Thanks.